# RSpec errors when run en masse, but not individually

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, delayed-job

Unfortunately I don't have a specific question (or clues), but was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

When I run all of my tests (rspec spec), I am getting two tests that fail specifically related to Delayed Job.

When I run this spec file in isolation (rspec ./spec/controllers/xxx_controller_spec.rb) all the tests pass...... Is this a common problem?  What should I be looking for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already mentioning it: isolation might be the solution. Usually I would guess that you have things in the database that are being changed and not cleaned up properly (or rather, are not not mocked properly).

In this case though I would suggest that, because the system is quite under a high workload, the delayed jobs are not being worked off fast enough. The challenge is with all asynchronous tasks that should be tested: you must not let the system run the delayed jobs, but mock the calls and just make sure that the delayed jobs have been received.

Sadly, with no examples, I can hardly point out the missing mocks. But make sure that all calls to delay_jobs and similar receive the correct data, but do not actually create and run those jobs - your specs will be faster, too. Make sure you isolate the function under test and  not call external dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the hints Nomad!  That's exactly what I"m looking for.  I realized that without posting any specific examples I couldn't expect any specific answers, but I felt it might be better to ask for a general tip than post 10,000 lines of code and hope people read through it :)  Cheers!

Comment: One thing that is useful to know is that rspec is designed to run its tests in randomized order each time.  The purpose of this design decision is to help you identify tests which are not properly isolated, by creating new combinations each run.  When you see an order-dependent failure you can reproduce the test order by using the --seed option, and copy-pasting the seed reported at the end of the run.  The end of a test run shows output like "Randomized with seed 12345".