# RSpec Tests fail with FactoryGirl, pass when isolated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I am upgrading an app from Rails 3 to Rails 4 and have a model called *item* with the following schema:

```
#===Schema Information
# Table name: items
#
#type :string
#maturity: string
```

and a spec with a series of test, but this one in particular is the one I have the issue with:

```
describe 'next_version' do
it 'should return the created_at date of the Item one version higher' do
first = FactoryGirl.create(:item, maturity: 'PRODUCTION')
second = FactoryGirl.create(:item, maturity: 'PREPRODUCTION', created_at: Time.now.in_time_zone)

expect(first.next_version_created_at.to_s)to eq second.created_at.utc.to_s)
```

The fix, I believe is easy enough.. just add..

```
 created_at: Time.now.in_time_zone
```

..to the Production item and done. However, the test passes if I run it by itself, and the entire spec passed (146 tests) in Rails 3, however when I run the entire spec now this one and 3 other similar cases fail, unless I run them alone.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You could try reloading factory girl before each test. Try adding this to the spec_helper.rb

```
config.before(:each) do
  FactoryGirl.reload
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens when you have data that isn't being properly cleaned up in the test database.

Make sure you have:

`config.use_transactional_fixtures = false`

in spec_helper.rb or rails_helper.rb.

See here:

[rspec test passes in isolation, but fails when run with other tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376595/rspec-test-passes-in-isolation-but-fails-when-run-with-other-tests)

[RSpec errors when run en masse, but not individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661629/rspec-errors-when-run-en-masse-but-not-individually)

Comment: I'm glad you pointed this out, however, that line is already in the spec_helper.rb, and we're already using DatabaseCleaner... Any other ideas?